# RDL File Decoding from Metaweb CGM Plugin

Tags: decoding

I was trying to decode red line markup file (file with .rdl extension) which is used by Metaweb CGM Plugin. For my work, I need to use this rdl file. I tried many options but there is no much information regarding rdl file in the internet. I also tried reaching out to the team who developed this Metaweb CGM Plugin, but they are not available. How can I proceed further to decode and get the data format of the rdl file.

Brief explanation regarding RDL

RDL is a markup file extension which is used to mark on top of the illustrations. It contains the informations about the drawn elements like line, text etc and properties associated with it

I tried to decode the binary format of the file into ASCII using hex editor, but the text also looks encoded. Also there is a company called Bentley systems which created .rdl files for markup in their application. But tried doing some R & D whether both the rdl which I am referring to and the .rdl file of Bentley system are same. But I couldn't get a proper information related to that. The information regarding rdl files in the internet is less.